# How do I remove file access for unknown user (as reported by Finder's File Info)?

Tags: macos, finder, permission, acl

File Info, under Sharing & Permissions, says "You have custom access" and lists:

```
Name          Privilege
joe (user)    Read & Write
staff (group) Read & Write
everyone      Read only
```

But `ls -le` says:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 egbert  staff  22806528 Jun  4 08:57 somefile.ext
```

This agrees with output from `stat -x somefile.ext`

```
Mode: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x) Uid: (  501/ egbert)  Gid: (   20/   staff)
```

joe is not a known user on this system (check with `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID` and "joe" is not in the list)

Finder won't let me "Choose new owner...". It says "The operation can't be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission." Yet I am egbert (see above) and I am owner and I have write privileges.

There does not appear to be any ACL on the file or any extended attributes (@ or +). `sudo chmod -N somefile.ext` fails with `chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file somefile.ext: Operation not supported.`

So who is joe if he's not known or listed among users? And how do I remove this user's access and restore privileges to me (egbert)? And why is there a disagreement between the Finder and what is reported by `ls` and `stat`?

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, since File Info lists a `joe` user, that user is known in some way on your system. Your question doesn't give enough information for an authoritative answer about that. Post a reply if you wish to pursue it.

You did not actually check for extended attributes on the file. To check for both extended attributes and an ACL, use

```
ls -le@ somefile.ext
```

To answer your explicit question: you probably cannot "Choose new owner" because you as `egbert` do not have permission to modify the directory that contains `somefile.ext`. A file's permissions determine who can read, write, or execute the contents of a file. The containing directory's permissions determine who can read or modify the attributes (such as permissions) of, or delete or rename, the files it contains.

If you wish to solve this problem and don't care about the reason it occurred, use Terminal as egbert to do the following:

1. `cd` to the containing directory
2. become root to avoid permissions issues:

   `sudo _your-favorite-shell_`
3. make a copy of the file's *contents*:

   `cat somefile.ext > somefile_copy.ext`
4. preserve its creation date:

   `touch -r somefile.ext somefile_copy.ext`
5. remove the original:

   `rm somefile.ext`
6. restore the original from the copy:

   `mv somefile_copy.ext somefile.ext`
7. stop being root:

   `exit`

Comment: This is really a comment asking for info - ie the id commands. However as this is an old question and a low rating I suspect you won't get that information

Comment: Also, the OP already stated that there is no user "joe" on their system, so `id joe` will not help.